# show product reference field with both add to cart and render product display format

Tags: commerce

i want to show product reference field with both add to cart and render product display format how i will do that?

Any help is appreciable.

I mean when i view a product it will show both add to cart form with all type of product variation.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh very easy i do it with template just create new template node--product--type--full.tpl.php  .

and use this

```
<?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);

      $options = $node->field_product[$node->language];
      foreach($options as $index => $option){
      $cmp_btn = drupal_get_form('properties_compare_add_form_' . commerce_product_comparison_create_key('commerce_product', $option['entity']), 'commerce_product', $option['entity'], $node->nid);
      $content['field_product'][$index]['commerce_product'][0]['cmp_btn']=$cmp_btn;
      $content['field_product'][$index]['commerce_product'][0]['cmp_btn']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('compare-form' . $option['product_id']));

      }
      print render($content);
    ?>
```

i remove the add to cart button in view an set the display to `render product`